# adding user to AD security group

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, directorysearcher

I have a pretty simple task – given the list (from file) of user names and their emails, synchronize it with the members of AD (Active Directory) users, meaning – add users that exist in the list and missing in AD group, and remove users that exist in AD group and missing in the list. The complication is that the company is very big and uses a lot of domains around the world based on their location – let’s say `it.comany.com`, `fr.company.com`, `uk.company.com`, `us.company.com`, etc. – each of them contains tons of users and users to add can be in any of them.

I use the following code to find the AD group:

```
var groupSearch = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry(“LDAP://company.com”), “(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN=TheNameOfTheADGroup))”);
var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(groupSearch.FindOne().Path);
```

and it finds the group successfully.

Now, I need to add user to this group (knowing only his username, like `willsmith`). This can be done by calling

```
dirEntry.Invoke(“Add”, new object[] { dirPath })
```

where `dirPath` is the FULL LDAP path of the user. I can get it by searching in specific domain, e.g.:

```
var userSearch = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry(“LDAP://xx.company.com”), “(&(ObjectClass=User)(CN=willsmith))”);
var dirPath = userSearch.FindOne().Path;
//and then use dirPath in Invoke(“Add”…) – see above
```

but the problem is that I don’t know which exact domain the user is in, and the number of domains is around 30, each user search takes about 2-3 seconds, so it will be a very long process.

Any ideas how to define domain for the user? Or maybe some other solution for the problem?

P.S. I do not use the new AD management capabilities introduced in .NET 3.5 (`PrincipalContext`, `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity`), because they don’t allow to specify the root for the search (which was the first parameter in `DirectorySearcher` constructor), which I need because the AD group is located in `company.com` domain not `us.company.com` from where is my account.

Comment: You can always create a specific `PrincipalContext` with a specific "starting point", e.g. you can create a context for `us.company.com` and another for `fr.company.com` etc. and then use the new .NET 3.5 stuff from there.....

Comment: marc_s,
this doesn't solve my problem - I don't know initially which domain the user is in, so for each specific user I will need to iterate thru the whole domain forest and create context for each domain to be able to find this user